# How can I recover an object who fires an eventListener event in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, event-listener

How can I access to an object who fires an eventListener event?

Let's say I have a mc:

```
var element = new MovieClip();
```

which has an eventlistener:

```
element.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, elementEventHandler);
```

And then, in the event handler, I want to add something to my mc:

```
function elementEventHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var b1:balloon = new balloon("ballon1"); //this is another class.

    event.target.addChild(b1);//this doesn't work.
}
```

So that is what I want to achieve... Recover the object who fired the event and then do crazy things with it (in this example, add another object in it).

If anybody has any idea, thanks in advance!

pd: yes, I know I can directly use the var element in this snippet, but in the real code I'm generating the mcs in a loop, according to a xml file.

Answer (score 1):

```
function elementEventHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // use the as-operator to cast the target into the class you need
    var element:DisplayObjectContainer = e.target as DisplayObjectContainer;

    // if the cast fails, element will be null, then we bail
    if(!element) return;

    // then, create your child and add it
    var b1:balloon = new balloon("ballon1");
    element.addChild(b1);
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I'm getting a runtime error with this approach: Loader class does not implement this method, at flash.display::Loader/addChild()  It seems that addchild does not work with the DisplayObjectContainer, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm very new in AS3. I've check the reference and now I understand that DisplayObjectContainer is the base class for all the visual containers classes. So I have no idea why I'm getting this error since addchild() is a DisplayObjectContainer method.

Comment: I figured out!! I used "event.currentTarget as DisplayObjectContainer" Instead of "event.target as DisplayObjectContainer". Now im trying to understand the difference. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting an error is probably that the event is not coming directly from `element` but instead from one of its descendant objects.

`"click"` is a bubbling event.

Check out event flow in the DOM Level 3 Events spec to understand how the capture, target, and bubbling phases work:

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#dom-event-architecture

So here's what I would do:

```
function elementEventHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (event.target != event.currentTarget)
        // If event is not from "element", ignore it.
        return;

    ...
}
```